# Setting the object type of a Maven property

Tags: maven, dbunit

How can set the object type of a property in a pom file?

I'm working with DBUnit to do DB exports and I'm trying to pass in the table parameter

```
        <configuration>
          <format>xml</format>
          <dest>target/dbunit/export.xml</dest>
          <tables>ACTIVITY_TYPE</tables>
        </configuration>
```

The tables attribute is supposed to have a type of 'Table[]' and running maven I get

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:dbunit-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-3:
export (default) on project CCSEWMS-db-export: Unable to parse configuration of
mojo org.codehaus.mojo:dbunit-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-3:export for parameter tables: Cannot assign configuration entry 'tables' with value 'ACTIVITY_TYPE' of type
 java.lang.String to property of type org.dbunit.ant.Table[] -> [Help 1]

So how can I convert my Strings into a Table[]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, this is how you specify the way to do it.

```
    <configuration>
      <driver>${driver}</driver>
      <url>${url}</url>
      <username>${username}</username>
      <password>${password}</password>
      <format>flat</format> 
      <tables>
        <list>
          <name>USER_SDO_MAPS</name>
        </list>
      </tables>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

The tables element is populated by specifying several of the other properties:

```
<configuration>
  <format>xml</format>
  <dest>target/dbunit/export.xml</dest>
  <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
  <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostname:portNumber:dbName</url>
  <username>userName</username>
  <password>password</password>
  <schema>schemaName</schema>
  <queries>
    <query>
      <name>QUERY_ID</name>
      <sql>SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE</sql>
    </query>
  ...
```